# How to copy paste data based on the number of days per month?

Tags: vba

Hi and good day everyone,

Basically I wish to extract the data based on the number of days per month. Please find the link below for better illustration:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B15JqLrOZtewamlRQ1ZMTmJZNWc&authuser=0

For example, D1 shows the current month is September. Therefore I will only need to extract the data from day 1-30. Also I will need to copy the ID and paste it at left column of the date for 30 times.

Any idea?

Thanks for your time!

Cheers,
Patch

Comment: Surely D1 would be a true date (e.g. 09/01/2014) that is formatted as *mmmm*...? If that is the case then `Day(DateSerial(Year(Range("D1").Value), Month(Range("D1").Value)+1, 0))` would give you the number of cells to copy.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, the value in D1 will be purely month, such as SEPTEMBER or AUGUST.

Comment: If you are typing *SEPTEMBER* or *AUGUST* into D1 then I would humbly suggest that is the wrong way to do it. I really cannot tell from your reply what you meant to say.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, perhaps can you try to open the link to have better illustration? D1 basically is from the source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll get you started on the macro code necessary to determine the number of days within a month when the month is spelled out as text.

```
Dim dys As Long
With ActiveSheet
    dys = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(.Cells(1, 4).Value & " 1, " & Year(Date)), 0))
    .Cells(2, 7).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    .Cells(2, 7) = "ID"
    .Cells(2, 8).Resize(1, 4) = .Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value
    .Cells(3, 7).Resize(dys, 1) = .Cells(1, 2).Value
    .Cells(3, 8).Resize(dys, 4) = .Cells(5, 1).Resize(dys, 4).Value
    Debug.Print dys
End With
```

With the last day of the month determined, it is a small matter to use that to resize the source/target regions of cells. I tried to determine the *best guess* for the cell addresses from your sample but the merged areas may have fouled things up.

[image: Transfer number of rows by month]

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, this is working perfectly! Just one concern, whether this macro is robust enough to identify whether there are 28 or 29 days in the February?

Comment: @patchlam - If you have a look at the code that determines the number of days in any month you will see that it appends the current year to the spelled-out month name in order to get the last day-of-the-month. You would have to be in a different year (with a different Feb 28/Feb 29) in order for it to foul up.